# Use of undeclared type 'ResponseJSONObjectSerializable'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Here's the code:

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

public protocol ResponseJSONObjectSerialiazable {
    init?(json: SwiftyJSON.JSON)
}

extension Alamofire.Request {
    public func responseObject<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable> (completionHandler:(NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<T>) -> Void) -> Self {
        //Error: Use of undeclared type 'ResponseJSONObjectSerializable'

    ...
    }
}
```

I'm using Swift 2.0 and Alamofire 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a simple typo `…liazable` vs. `…lizable`.